# Prevent MouseClick event after MouseMove

Tags: c#, .net

I have a user control within a tab page that is vertically dragable. The control is also selectable. I want the user to be able to click on the item to select it, but I don't want the MouseClick event to fire when they've finished dragging it - only the MouseUp event should fire. Ie. The item shouldn't be selected after a user finishes dragging it. Any advice?

Comment: Are you using WPF or ASP.NET? Can you please show your event handlers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is WinForms.

When you say you have a user control, do you mean you have a class that is derived from `UserControl`? In that case, you can override the `OnMouseClick` method and not call `base.OnMouseClick(e)`, which will prevent `MouseClick` from firing.

Like SamHi suggested, you can use a boolean that is set to `true` when dragging starts, and once `OnMouseClick` is called, you can set that boolean to false, allowing for mouse clicks to occur after dragging is complete.

Example:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    bool dragging = false;

    // ...

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragging)
        {
            // We've finished dragging, don't call MouseClick
            dragging = false;
            return;
        }

        // Not dragging, fire MouseClick
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a drag bool that equals true while you are dragging, then having it turn off after a short timer runs. This way, you can add an if statement in the MouseClick event to see if it was recently dragged.